# Select positive solution based on value of parameter

Tags: equation-solving

I want to select positive solutions to `Solve[]`, but as the sign of the solutions depend on the value of some parameters/other variable, I am not sure how to do this?

For example, how do I select the positive solution of $x^2=a^2$ given that `a` is positive? My code below doesn't work...

```
sol=Solve[x^2==a^2,x]
Select[sol, (x/.#)>0&]
```

Also, could I have specified this directly in the Solve function, solving only for x positive knowing that a is positive?

Thanks!

Comment: `Simplify[Solve[x^2 == a^2 && x > 0 && a > 0, x, Reals], 
 Assumptions -> {a > 0}]`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Reduce`

```
Reduce[x^2==a^2&& x>0,x,Reals]
```

which gives you two solutions depending on the sign of `a`:

> (a < 0 && x == Sqrt[a^2]) || (a > 0 && x == Sqrt[a^2])

So if you make it more strict you will get one solution:

`Reduce[x^2==a^2&& x>0&& a>0,x,Reals]`

> a > 0 && x == a

Comment: Nice, thanks @MathX! Is there however any way I could use based on the output from Solve? Thanks!

Comment: `Solve[{x^2 == a^2, a > 0, x > 0}, x] // Simplify[#, a > 0] &`  evaluates to  `{{x -> a}}`